# Print iframe using jquery inside iframe on iOS and Android

Tags: jquery, ios, iframe, printing

How can I print an iframe window using jquery inside the iframe on iOS and Android. I have the following code which works for IE, Chrome, and Firefox, but on Android it appears to be printing the whole parent window with iframe on top.

```
if (document.queryCommandSupported('print')) {
    // IE and Chrome
    document.execCommand('print', false, null);
} else if((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1) || (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/))) {
    // Android or iOS
    $('iframe').contentWindow.focus();
    $('iframe').contentWindow.print();
} else {
    // Firefox
    window.print();
}
```

I've tried selecting the iframe using the iframe tag but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#iframe').contents();` to get only contents of frame.

Comment: I'm using Jack Moore's colorbox and I've tried the following but the print preview in Safari on iPad shows a blank page:    $('.cboxIframe').focus();
$('.cboxIframe').contents().print();

Comment: Is the frame in same domain? If not, cross domain policy won't allow you to access the content.

Comment: Yes it's on the same domain.